# How to extract a subnode value from XML text?

Tags: xml, delphi

I'm trying to extract the value of a sub node named *left*, which is inside a node named *design* but an `EInvalidPointer` occurs.

I'm using Delphi 2007 and this is the XML text:

```
<design>
  <top>
    0
  </top>
  <left>
    5
  </left>
  <height>
    177
  </height>
  <width>
    130
  </width>
</design>
```

And this is the code:

```
uses
  XMLDoc, XMLIntf...

var                  
  Stream : TStream;
  Doc : TXMLDocument;
  Node : IXMLNode;
begin
  Stream := TStringStream.Create(Memo1.Lines.Text);
  try
    Doc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
    try
      Doc.LoadFromStream(Stream);
      Node := Doc.ChildNodes.FindNode('design');
      if(Node <> nil) then
      begin
        Node := Node.ChildNodes.FindNode('left'); //EInvalidPointer here
        if(Node <> nil) then
        begin
          //...
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Doc.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Could someone help me understanding what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Doc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
```

When you pass `nil` to the constructor of `TXMLDocument` that means that you are asking for the lifetime to be managed by reference counting. Which means that you need to declare `Doc` as an interface reference:

```
var
  Doc: IXMLDocument;
```

Naturally when you do this you do not call `Free` on `Doc`, and the `try/finally` block can be removed. Reference counting of interfaces is automatically managed by code that the compiler emits on your behalf.

If you want to use a class reference, as your code is currently configured, you would need to pass an owner to the constructor.

Comment: Why using TButton in the same way doesn't cause problems? Is this a lucky case or is there something that makes TXMLDocument behave like that?

Comment: @ExDev, Tbutton is not an interfaced object.

Comment: TXMLDocument is special

Comment: This is [documented behavior](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument): "*When TXMLDocument is created without an Owner, it behaves like an interfaced object. That is, when all references to its interface are released, the TXMLDocument instance is automatically freed. When TXMLDocument is created with an Owner, however, it behaves like any other component, and is freed by its Owner.*"